# Just start to learn 2D array in Python. Why both codes generate different outputs just by changing place of col=[ ]

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

Code that works perfectly:

```
    rows, cols = (4,2)
    arr=[]
    for i in range(rows):
        col = []
        for j in range(cols):
            col.append(0)
        arr.append(col)
    print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Alternative implementation:

```
    rows, cols = (4,2)
    arr=[]
    col = []
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            col.append(0)
        arr.append(col)
    print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Why both codes generate different outputs just by changing place of col where an empty list is assigned to it. I have tried to get concept with trace table but got confused.

Comment: because in each iteration inside loop, in  your second code, col variable resets to an empty list

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the classic Python blunders.  Your entire second program contains EXACTLY two lists.  There's one bound to `col`, and one bound to `arr`, and the one bound to `arr` contains multiple references to the first list.  It does not contain 4 different lists, it contains 4 links to the SAME list.

To do what you want, you need to create a NEW empty list in each iteration, as you have done in the first example.